# VirtualBox fails to start

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10-preview

I know that multiple questions have been asked related to this topic; but my error is entirely different
This is the exact error I get:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Arch.

Call to VidMessageSlotMap failed: Last=0xc000000d/87     (VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

It should be noted that I have a windows 10 home edition. It doesn't come with a Hyper-V feature. Even to use Hyper-V, I will have to buy a professional edition

Edit:

I installed `vmware`. It isn't working, but at least giving a nice error message saying `device guard` and `credential guard` should be turned off. As I said, I've Windows 10 Home edition and it doesn't have either of the two. Will anyone explain the reason?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VirtualBox fails to start with VERR\_NEM\_VM\_CREATE\_FAILED](https://superuser.com/questions/1442766/virtualbox-fails-to-start-with-verr-nem-vm-create-failed)

Comment: No it doesn't. Please look at the `VidMessageSlotMap failed` error. Others have a different error

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1190456/virtualbox-0x80004005

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/785072/e-fail-0x80004005-when-running-linux-through-windows-8-virtualbox

Comment: Happening to me too. Tried every troubleshooting process found. Windows 10 build 19041. VirtualBox Version 6.1.0 r135406 (Qt5.6.2)

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 "Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Ubuntu 18.04. Call to VidMessageSlotMap failed: Last=0xc000000d/87 (VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED). Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005) Component: ConsoleWrap Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}"

Comment: @JesusIniesta, my issue got resolved when I switched from a Windows insider build to a normal build. Just for the sake of verifying, I again (stupidly) upgraded to an insider build, and there was again an issue. Are you running an insider build?

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 Before choosing to use an Insider Build, capture an image the `C:` partition using `DISM` _(see the **Imaging** and **Commands** [**section**](https://superuser.com/a/1503102/529800))_, as going back to a non-Insidier's build will often require a clean install of Windows. .

Comment: Any info on How to disable Device/Credential Guard would really be helpful. The fact that I know the issue but can't resolve it is really annoying me. I searched all over on Google, but all they show is for Pro versions. As far as I know, Windows Home doesn't come with these features (at least mine didn't)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I myself found an answer. The solution is very simple (Do Take a backup of ye data before implementing). Go to the BIOS and reset the TPM settings(!!!!WARNING This clears your account credentials including your Windows Hello PIN if you have it set up!!!!). Then reboot and lo! bob's your uncle :). To all of you Geeks out there, what setting must have got changed when I reset TPM?? I mean, I don't remember changing TPM settings.

One more thing, the solution works for insider as well as non-insider builds

Answer (score 1):

I suspected, after reading OP's own answer, that my activation of Windows Hello PIN had hosed my VirtualBox install; even when attempting to set up brand new VMs, they all failed to start with the same error. I instead decided to try a different tack though: I reinstalled VirtualBox (over the top of my old install).

My old version was 6.1.18, and I reinstalled 6.1.30 over it -- as soon as the install had completed (I had to reinstall the VirtualBox Extension Pack as well because the old one was out of date) I tried to fire up a VM, and *boom*, it runs like a champ!